# Jest Coverage 100% even tests are failed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, istanbul

Jest Version
24.9.0

Steps to reproduce

1. I am using vue@2.6.14, @vue/cli-service@4.5.18 , jest@24.9.0, @vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest@4.5.18 , typescript@3.9.10
2. Previously I was using node 14 and esnext. Jest Coverage was working fine, there was no issues
3. Later I updated node 14 to 16 and esnext to es2019 and configured snapshots as well, then  lost my coverage. Then reverted my changes, still facing coverage issue.

Even if any tests failed, its giving 100% coverage

Jest Configuration :

```
collectCoverageFrom: ["src/**/*.vue"]

"test:unit": "npm run requirements-check && vue-cli-service test:unit --colors --coverage --maxWorkers=4 -u"
```

Node: 14.15.4
npm: 6.14.10

Sample testcase (its enough to get 100% coverage even file has multiple functions) :

```
describe("Can able to see page is mounted", () => {
  let i18n: VueI18n;
  let localVue: VueConstructor<Vue>;
  let routerMock: any;
  let wrapper: Wrapper<test& {
    [key: string]: any;
   }>;

beforeEach(() => {
    localVue = createLocalVue();
    localVue.use(plugins);
    localVue.use(VueI18n);
    localVue.prototype.$notify = jest.fn();
    localVue.config.ignoredElements = [/vl*/];

    window.scrollTo = jest.fn();

    routerMock = {
        $router: {
        replace: jest.fn(),
        push: jest.fn(),
        go: jest.fn()
      }
    };

    wrapper = mount(test, {
      i18n,
      localVue,
      mocks: routerMock,
      directives: {
        "full-screen-loading": jest.fn()
      },
      stubs: ["router-link", "router-view"]
    });
  });

  it("test", () => {
     expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true);
     expect(wrapper.find(".test").exists()).toBe(true);
     expect(wrapper.element).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Comment: Coverage means the code is being run. I don't think it matters whether the test passed or not?

Comment: @evolutionxbox even if we are not write complete testcases for that file, coverage is 100%. not predicting uncovered lines anymore

Comment: Does it still say 100% when you remove all the tests? If all your code is in one function it will say 100% as soon as you just call the function. If this is the case, try extracting some functions so you can test them separately. You can have 100% coverage even with bad tests that don't test anything.

Comment: if i have at least one testcase(one it statement), its showing 100% coverage(one testcase is enough, if i remove the testcase file, statements and lines are 0% coverage and functions & branches are 100%) @H3AR7B3A7

Comment: Well that is weird. Can you add some code/tests to the question?

Comment: added but code is same, before updating package it was working fine (predicted uncovered lines).

Comment: I just found that jest checking props, component class ,imports and not checking functions, thats why coverage always 100%

Comment: Update : its happening due to latest version of one package, yet to find which one is that